# Node.js commander with optional+variadic arguments

Tags: node.js, node-commander

Please help me get node's `commander` module to parse arguments the way I want.

I'm looking to upload a list of files to a named database. There is a default database name, so the user shouldn't *need* to include a database parameter.

I'd like this command to work as following:

```
>>> ./upload.js --db ReallyCoolDB /files/uploadMe1.txt /files/uploadMe2.txt
(uploads "uploadMe1.txt" and "uploadMe2.txt" to database "ReallyCoolDB")

>>> ./upload.js /files/uploadMe1.txt /files/uploadMe2.txt
(uploads "uploadMe1.txt" and "uploadMe2.txt" to the default database)

>>> ./upload.js --db ReallyCoolDB
(returns an error; no files provided)
```

How can I implement this with `commander`? I've tried a number of things already, currently I'm stuck with this code which doesn't work:

```
// upload.js:

#!/usr/bin/env node

var program = require('commander');
program
  .version('0.1.0')
  .description('Upload files to a database')
  .command('<path1> [morePaths...]')
  .option('-d, --db [dbName]', 'Optional name of db', null)
  .action(function(path1, morePaths) {
    
    // At this point I simply want:
    // 1) a String "dbName" var
    // 2) an Array "paths" containing all the paths the user provided
    var dbName = program.db || getDefaultDBName();
    var paths = [ path1 ].concat(morePaths || []);
    console.log(dbName, paths);
    
    // ... do the upload ...
    
  })
  .parse(process.argv);
```

When I try to run `./upload.js`, I get no output!

**How can I use commander to accept a single optional parameter, and a non-empty list of strings??**

EDIT: Thanks to Rob Raisch's answer I've solved my problem! The solution is to use `usage` instead of `action`, do all work after the `program` commands (instead of within an `action` function), work with `program.db` and `program.args`, and manually ensure that `program.args` is non-empty:

```
var program = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.1.0')
    .description('Upload files to a database')
    .usage('[options] <path1> [morePaths ...]') // This improves "--help" output
    .option('-d, --db [dbName]', 'Optional name of db', null)
    .parse(process.argv);

var dbName = program.db || getDefaultDBName();
var paths = program.args;

if (!paths.length) {
    console.log('Need to provide at least one path.');
    process.exit(1);
}

// Do the upload!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [README.md](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) file for the `commander` command line processing module answers your use case in its second paragraph:

"Options with commander are defined with the .option() method, also serving as documentation for the options. The example below parses args and options from process.argv, **leaving remaining args as the program.args** array which were not consumed by options."

Comment: So what is the correct way to accept an optional parameter + a non-empty list with `commander`? Should I use commander to parse the optional parameter, and then manually parse `program.args`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your first example code declares a subcommand with slightly the wrong syntax (it should have a command name too). But you don't want a subcommand anyway, so changing one line will make your program work as written with the arguments added to the program.

```js
// .command('sub-command-name <path1> [morePaths...]')
.arguments('<path1> [morePaths...]')
```

2. If you want one or more parameters in a single parameter (a non-empty array) then declare it as a single variadic argument with a required command-argument like:

```js
.arguments('<paths...>')
```

or use the new syntax for an argument at a time (so more like adding subcommands and options):

```js
.argument('<paths...>', 'description')
```

3. It looks like the `--db` option should have an option-argument if it is used, so I suggest `<dbName>` rather than `[dnName]`.
4. You could specify the default db with the option so it can be seen in the help too.

Putting it all together:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var program = require('commander');
program
  .version('0.1.0')
  .description('Upload files to a database')
  .argument('<paths...>', 'one or more files to upload')
  .option('-d, --db <dbName>', 'name of db', getDefaultDBName())
  .action(function(paths, options) {
    
    // At this point I simply want:
    // 1) a String "dbName" var
    // 2) an Array "paths" containing all the paths the user provided
    console.log(options.db, paths);
    
    // ... do the upload ...
    
  })
  .parse(process.argv);
```